# How to set Transformation dependencies in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

I am working with Pentaho Data Integration (aka Kettle) and I have several Transformations, let's call them A, B, C, D, E. B depends on A, D depends on C and E depends on B and D. In a job I'd like to run A, B and C, D in parallel:

```
      -> A -> B _
Start>            \
       -> C -> D----> E
```

where A and C run in parallel. Is there any way to execute E only iff B AND D were successful? Right now, looking at the Job metrics, E gets executed as soon as either B OR D are finished.

Comment: What type of dependency you have? There are multiple steps which you can use according to your requirement.

Comment: E has to execute only when both B and D are successfull.

Comment: Dependency mean what type of logic is present in B and D? at job level you can check steps like wait for sql , wait for, simple evaluation. you can avoid creating job and check transformation level steps like, Delay Row,blocking steps, blocking this step until one step finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Separate A,B,C,D into a separate single sub job:

Start -> JobABCD -> E

Then you have JobABCD contain the following:

```
      -> A -> B _
Start>            \
       -> C -> D----> Success
```

This will give you the following benefits:
- The two job streams A->B and C->D will run in parallel.
- E will only run after B AND D have finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you can abort then something like this will work... if you need to let C + D run to completion then you can use a variant of this.

Grr..can't embed pictures...basically you can use a condition and results fields and errors to control the job(s). While this isn't really dependancies per se I will do what you are after. so after each job you can have a condition that checks the result field for a value true you move on false you error out. Of course you will have to make sure there is a results field returned from the job.

[A sample job Picture only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Pay.png)

Answer (score 0):

For that, it is better to use DBT, this data transformation tool automatically detects dependencies and executes processes in an orderly manner.